# Why does Access close/reopen when a vba DoCmd.OutputTo command is executed to create a PDF of a report

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, report

I'm using the following two lines of code to try to create a  PDF of a filtered report.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptContactDetails", acViewPreview, , "contactsid=" & TempVars!RecordUnderEdit

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptContactDetails", acFormatPDF, "D:\Temp\CurrentContactDetails.pdf"
```

If the first line is omitted the DoCmd.OutputTo command works fine and a PDF of the full report is correctly created.  However, as I want to create a PDF of a filtered version of the report, I am opening it first with a filter applied (which works fine).  If I do that though, when the DoCmd.OutputTo  is executed Access says it's creating the PDF but then just shuts down and tries to reopen, prompting me to save a backup of the database.  Only a zero length .tmp file is created in the target directory.

I have tried replacing the TempVar with a simple numeric contactsID but the same thing happens.  I also use the exact same technique (virtually identical code) in another database on the same PC and it works absolutely fine, correctly creating a PDF of the filtered version of the report.  I'm using the latest version of Access (Microsoft Access v16.0 object library).

Any suggestions as to what might be happening (why Access closes) would be most welcome - I'm a hobbyist not a programmer/software developer!

Comment: You must have the filter in the output command, not in the preview command. Access seems to get confused when the same report is opened for preview and for output.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie  Thanks for the comment.  There is no way that I can see of adding the filter to the OutputTo command, that is why the filtered report is opened first.  Please advise how that could be done.

Answer (score 1):

Per MS Access docs, [DoCmd.OutputTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.outputto), the parameter *ObjectName* is actually optional. If left blank, method will output the active object. However, to dynamically filter a report for output, do not use print preview `acViewPreview` but report view `acViewReport`

```vb
' OPEN IN REPORT VIEW
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptContactDetails", acViewReport, , "contactsid=" & TempVars!RecordUnderEdit

' LEAVE OBJECTNAME BLANK
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, , acFormatPDF, "D:\Temp\CurrentContactDetails.pdf"

' CLOSE REPORT
DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptContactDetails"
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this suggestion - I have tried your suggested code but sadly still have the same problem.  Also, as mentioned in my original post I looked back carefully at the other database I created that uses this technique and that uses acViewPreview when opening the report and also explicitly mentions the report in the OutputTo command and it works fine. There is no code in the report, though it does contain three subreports - that is the only difference.  Also as I said if I don't open the filtered report first a PDF of the full unfiltered report is correctly generated.

Answer (score 0):

one solution is to manage the filtering as part of the query def - of the query that is the record source of the report.

have the report sourced on qryABC.  say it is just the table with no criteria.

then change the query def of qryABC with a sql statement that add criteria i.e Red widgets... you can find online tutorial on changing query def of a query.

then fire the export of the report.  it's a 2 step process but will work.

Comment: Thanks for this - I have implemented a workaround using a similar approach.  My main reason for the question however was to try to understand why Access was shutting down and restarting, since I had used identical code in another dtabase on the same PC without any issues.